# What is the correct way to get error count Percentage using influxDB query

Tags: influxdb

I'm new to influxDB trying to get the error count and pass count percentage. when i checked online i got the below query to calculate the error rate:

```
SELECT sum("errorCount")/count("responseTime") FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE $timeFilter
```

i want to know. why sum(errorcount) is divided by sum(responseTime) and is this the correct way to calculate error percentage. Please throw some light on this. Any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rate != percentage.

The above query gives rate, ie how many errors occurred over total response time or the frequency at which errors occur.

The error percentage OTOH would be what percentage of all responses within a given time frame were errors, ie `sum(errors)*100/sum(allHits)`